# How do I display my function in Sheet2 where data in another Sheet1, in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Courtesy :Jean-Pierre Verhulst

In my below GOOGLE SHEETS formulae , my data (Column A ) is in Sheet1, how do i change so that it displays the result sequence in **Sheet2** ?

```
=filter(row(indirect("A"&A1&":A"&+sort(A1:A, 1, 0))), isna(match(row(indirect("A"&A1&":A"&+sort(A1:A, 1, 0))), A1:A,0)))
```

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/5868559/identify-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally avoid *volatile* `INDIRECT` set-ups, even though I understand that that function is volatile only in Excel, and apparently not in Sheets.

`=FILTER(SEQUENCE(MAX(Sheet1!A:A)-MIN(Sheet1!A:A)+1,1,MIN(Sheet1!A:A)),ISNA(MATCH(SEQUENCE(MAX(Sheet1!A:A)-MIN(Sheet1!A:A)+1,1,MIN(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!A:A,0)))`

Comment: Thank you Jos Woolley.. it worked. I owe you a treat